# Connect to serial port in Java using RXTX

Tags: eclipse, serial-port, arduino, rxtx

I'm using [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) to communicate with Arduino, through the Arduino platform. I can open a port using Eclipse or Arduino, but I can't connect to an opened port using Eclipse. I would like to send integers using Eclipse through the Arduino platform, and then received by the Arduino.
How can I connect Eclipse to Arduino's serial port?

This is my actual code (I found it in *[Utilisation des ports COM en Java avec RXTX [Résolu]](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d699216/java/general-java/utilisation-ports-com-java-rxtx-resolu/)* (is in French)):

```
import gnu.io.UnsupportedCommOperationException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestSerialPort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Le port est-il ouvert? ");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Vous avez saisi : " + str);
        String s1 = "non";

        if ( s1.equals(str))
        {
            final RS232 serial = new RS232();
            System.out.println("-   Ouverture du port   -");
            serial.SetPort("COM3");
            serial.SetVitesse(4800);
            serial.SetNbBits(8);
            serial.SetParite("AUCUNE");
            serial.SetStop("1");
            serial.SetControle("matériel");

            serial.OuvrirPort();
            System.out.println("-   Envoie de l'information   -");
            serial.EcrireInt(9);
            System.out.println(" Le recu " + serial.GetCRecu());

            serial.EffacerCRecu();
            serial.FermerPort();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}

import gnu.io.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class RS232 {
    private OutputStream outStream; //Flux d'Ã©criture du port
    private InputStream in; //Flux de lecture du port
    private CommPortIdentifier portId; //Identifiant du port
    private RXTXPort sPort; //Le port sÃ©rie
    private String s; //String de retour d'info
    private int vitesse = 4800;
    private int NbBits = SerialPort.DATABITS_8;
    private String NomPort = "COM3";
    private int Parite = SerialPort.PARITY_NONE;
    private int Stop = SerialPort.STOPBITS_1;
    private int Controle = SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE;
    private RXTXCommDriver w32Driver = new RXTXCommDriver();
    private EcoutePort EcoutePort1;
    private BufferedReader bufRead;

    public RS232(){

    }

    //RecupÃ©ration du nom du port
    public String SetPort(String port){
        NomPort = port;
        s = "";
        try {
            portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(NomPort);
            s = "port OK";
        }
        catch (NoSuchPortException e) {
            s = "port innexistant";
        }
        return s;
    }

    //Renvoi du nom du port
    public String GetPort(){
        return portId.toString();
    }

    //Recuperation de la vitesse de transmission
    public void SetVitesse(int v){
        vitesse = v;
    }

    //Retour de la vitesse de transmission
    public int GetVitesse(){
        return vitesse;
    }

    //Recupertion du nombre de bits de donÃ©es
    public String SetNbBits(int b){
        s = "";
        if (b == 5){
            NbBits = RXTXPort.DATABITS_5;
            s = "5 bits de donnÃ©e";
        }
        else if (b == 6){
            NbBits = RXTXPort.DATABITS_6;
            s = "6 bits de donnÃ©e";
        }
        else if (b == 7){
            NbBits = RXTXPort.DATABITS_7;
            s = "7 bist de donnÃ©e";
        }
        else if (b == 8){
            NbBits = RXTXPort.DATABITS_8;
            s = "8 bits de donnÃ©e";
        }
        else {
            s = "Nombre de bits de donnÃ©e incompatible";
        }
        // System.out.println(s);
        return s;
    }

    //Retour du nombre de bits de donnÃ©es
    public int getNbBits(){
        int b = 0;
        if ( NbBits == RXTXPort.DATABITS_5){
            b = 5;
        }
        else if (NbBits == RXTXPort.DATABITS_6){
            b = 6;
        }
        else if ( NbBits == RXTXPort.DATABITS_7){
            b = 7;
        }
        else if ( NbBits == RXTXPort.DATABITS_8){
            b = 8 ;
        }
        return b;
    }

    //Recuperation de la parite
    public String SetParite(String parite){
        s = "";
        if (parite.equals("AUCUNE")){
            Parite = RXTXPort.PARITY_NONE;
            s = "Pas de paritÃ©";
        }
        else if (parite.equals("PAIRE")){
            Parite = RXTXPort.PARITY_EVEN;
            s = "ParitÃ© paire";
        }
        else if (parite.equals("IMPAIRE")){
            Parite = RXTXPort.PARITY_ODD;
            s = "ParitÃ© impaire";
        }
        else if (parite.equals("MARQUE")){
            Parite = RXTXPort.PARITY_MARK;
            s = "ParitÃ© marquÃ©e";
        }
        else if (parite.equals("ESPACE")){
            Parite = RXTXPort.PARITY_SPACE;
            s = "ParitÃ© espace";
        }
        else {
            s = "ParitÃ© inconnue";
        }
        // System.out.println(s);
        return s;
    }

    //Retour de la parite
    public String GetParite(){
        s = "";
        if (Parite == RXTXPort.PARITY_NONE){
            s = "AUCUNE";
        }
        else if (Parite == RXTXPort.PARITY_EVEN){
            s = "PAIRE";
        }
        else if (Parite == RXTXPort.PARITY_ODD){
            s = "IMPAIRE";
        }
        else if (Parite == RXTXPort.PARITY_MARK){
            s = "MARQUE";
        }
        else if (Parite == RXTXPort.PARITY_SPACE){
            s = "ESPACE";
        }
        return s;
    }

    //Recuperation du nombre de bits de stop
    public String SetStop(String stop){
        s = "";
        if (stop.equals("1")){
            Stop = RXTXPort.STOPBITS_1;
            s = "1 bit de stop";
        }
        else if (stop.equals("2")){
            Stop = RXTXPort.STOPBITS_2;
            s = "2 bits de stop";
        }
        else if (stop.equals("1,5")){
            Stop = RXTXPort.STOPBITS_1_5;
            s = "bit de stop 1,5";
        }
        else {
            s = "bit de stop inconnu";
        }
        // System.out.println(s);
        return s;
    }

    //Retour du nombre de bits de stop
    public String GetStop(){
        s = "";
        if (Stop == RXTXPort.STOPBITS_1){
            s = "1";
        }
        else if (Stop == RXTXPort.STOPBITS_2){
            s = "2";
        }
        else if (Stop == RXTXPort.STOPBITS_1_5){
            s = "1,5";
        }
        return s;
    }

    //Recuperation du controle
    public void SetControle(String controle){
        if (controle.equals("matÃ©riel")){
            Controle = SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN;
        }
        else if (controle.equals("Xon/Xoff")){
            Controle = SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_XONXOFF_IN;
        }
        else {
            Controle = SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE;
        }
    }

    //Retour du controle
    public String GetControle(){
        String c = null;
        if (Controle == SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE){
            c = "aucun";
        }
        if (Controle == SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN){
            c = "matÃ©riel";
        }
        if (Controle == SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_XONXOFF_IN){
            c = "Xon/Xoff";
        }
        return c;
    }

    //Ouvrir le port et les flux
    public void OuvrirPort(){
        w32Driver.initialize();
        //Ouverture du port
        try {
            sPort = (RXTXPort) portId.open("java_rs232", 2000);
        }
        catch (PortInUseException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

        if (sPort != null) {
            //RÃ¨gle les paramÃ¨tres de la connexion
            try {
                sPort.setFlowControlMode(Controle);
                sPort.setSerialPortParams(vitesse,
                                          NbBits,
                                          Stop,
                                          Parite);

                //RÃ©cupÃ©ration du flux de lecture et Ã©criture du port
                outStream = sPort.getOutputStream();
                in = sPort.getInputStream();
                bufRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sPort.getInputStream()));
                EcoutePort1 = new EcoutePort(in);

                (new Thread(EcoutePort1)).start();
            }
            catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
              System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    // Retour de la chaine recu
    public String GetCRecu(){
        String c = "";
        if (sPort != null) {
            c = EcoutePort1.Recu();
        }
        return c;
    }

    //Effacer la chaine recu
    public void EffacerCRecu(){
        if (sPort != null) {
            EcoutePort1.EffacerRecu();
        }
    }

    // Ecrire un caractere
    public void EcrireChar(char envoie){
        if (sPort != null) {
            try {
                //Demande de poids
                outStream.write((int) envoie);
                outStream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    //Ecrire un tablea de bytes
    public boolean EcrireBytes(byte[] envoie){
        boolean b = false;

        if (sPort != null) {
            try {
                outStream.write(envoie);
                outStream.close();
                b = true;
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
        return b;
    }

    public boolean EcrireInt(int envoie){
        boolean b = false;

        if (sPort != null) {
            try {
                outStream.write(envoie);
                outStream.close();
                b = true;
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
        return b;
    }

    //Fermer le port
    public void FermerPort(){
        if (sPort != null) {
        try {
            outStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

        EcoutePort1.stopThread();
            sPort.close();
        }
    }
}


//thread d'ecoutedu port

class EcoutePort implements Runnable{
    private boolean running = true;
    private InputStream in;
    private String CaractRecu;
    private String SRecu = new String();

    public EcoutePort(InputStream in){
        this.in = in;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while (running){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len = -1;
            try
            {
                while ( ( len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1 )
                {
                    CaractRecu = new String(buffer,0,len);
                    SRecu = SRecu.concat(CaractRecu);
                    //byte[]  RetourTrame = CaractRecu.getBytes();
                    //for (int t = 0;t<RetourTrame.length;t++){
                    //  System.out.println((int)RetourTrame[t]& 0xff);
                    //}
                    try {
                        // pause
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException ex) {}

                }
             }
             catch ( IOException e )
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }

     //Arrette le thread
     public void stopThread(){
         this.running = false;
     }

     //Eface les caractere recu
     public void EffacerRecu(){
         SRecu = "";
     }

     //Renvoi les caractere recu
     public String Recu(){
         return SRecu;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Actually, i can send information with Arduino, and i receive it with Eclipse. But, i want eclipse to send information to Arduino.

Comment: I can send int and receive others using eclipse and Arduino. I will upload code.